# I have an IF statement but its not working as i intended it too

Tags: excel, formula

I have a need for an IF statement to add time if a cell shows as No.

So in Cell F2 i need the IF statement to look in Cell E2, if the cell shows No, i need it to then add 10 minutes to Cell D2 and then return the result,

I have so far tried this, `=IF(E2="No",D2+10,"")` however this doesnt give the correct output. In cell D2 the time is 10:48:00 it should show as 10:58:00 what have i done wrong here? Am i on the right track?

Im not sure what else i can try in the interim as the above seems to be the most logical method?

Comment: What is it doing *instead of* showing 10:58:00?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, by accident though, I changed the statement to read `=IF(E2="No",D2+"0:10","")`

Comment: Glad to see that worked @John, date math is usually a portion of a day, your first try added 10 days in stead of minutes.  Another result that may be more flexible would be: =IF(E2="No", D2 + (10 * .00069), "")

Comment: .00069 is equivalent to one minute: 1 / (24 * 60)